# Ajax form - Multiple select elements

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a form with multiple select elements with an #ajax callback on change. The ajax is working but the problem is that I can't figure out how to find which select has triggered the ajax. All ajax callbacks point to the same function.

Any ideas on how to find which select was changed?

Thanks.

Comment: Got a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make the distinction by checking [`$form_state['triggering_element']`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7#comment-16054):

```
switch ($form_state['triggering_element']['#name']) {
  case 'select1':
    // Do something
    break;
  case 'select2':
    // Do something
    break;
  // ...
}
```